# Multiselect WPF combo box

Tags: wpf, combobox, multi-select

I have a WPF combo box which `ItemsSource` is `ObservableCollection<User>`, where `User` has `string Name` and `bool IsChecked`.

Also I have

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Width="20" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

, which nicely shows check boxes before each name and allows me to check/uncheck users.

What I need is to make combo box selected item to show not the selected user but all checked usernames separated by comma, ideally (if resultant string is too long) with ellipsis in the middle, i. e. "Alice, Bart...mew, John".

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit tricky to implement, but certainly can be done.

First of all you'll want to replace the drop-down bar/button with a TextBlock, so you'll need to modify the control's template. Place the edit cursor anywhere inside the parent ComboBox declaration so that the control appears in the Properties panel at the bottom right. In properties, find Miscellaneous -> Template at the bottom, then click on the little down-arrow to the right and select "Convert to new resource". This will template out the control so that you can start editing it.

Next, find the ToggleButton's ContentPresenter inside the ControlTemplate. You'll want to change it's Content binding to point to a property in your view models which I'll call `Names`:

```
<!--<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>-->
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{Binding Names}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

The next change is to also add a binding to your CheckBox Command property called "NamesChangedCommand" which will be called whenever the user changes the state of a CheckBox:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Width="20" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=DataContext.NamesChangedCommand}" />
```

Then back in your view model, all you have to do is implement this command and have it generate the new name list. Here's how you'd do that in MVVM Toolkit:

```
    [RelayCommand]
    public void NamesChanged()
    {
        this.Names = String.Join(", ",
            this.Items
                .Where(item => item.IsChecked)
                .Select(item => item.Name));
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string names = "";
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark! Thank you very much for your answer, looks like it's pointed me in the right direction. There are two issues with your proposal: 1) It removes that 'check mark' which represents a combo's toggle button  and 2) if I select (not check) some item then I see both the "Names" and selected item.

Comment: That "Convert to new resource" command also generates a ContentPresenter presenter, so it looks promising to play with it instead of defining ToggleButton.Template. I'll try and will add another comment if I'll be successful, but if you have any additional ideas it's highly appreciated. P.S. How do you make multiline comment here?  ))

Comment: @eggor sorry, I was in a bit of a rush when I answered, instead of templating out the ToggleButton you can just bind the ContentPresenter's Content to `Names` instead. I've updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @eggor also, SO comments unfortunately don't support newlines [by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this returned 'check mark'. But problem #2 is still here. Could be solved by removing ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}", in this case item selection just does nothing. Do you think there is a way to make item selection to toggle check box just like in xceed  CheckComboBox from Andy's answer?

Comment: And what about ellipsis - there is no out of the box way to put them in the middle of the string, but there is a way to put them at the end: '        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ContentPresenter.Resources>'

Comment: Hi @MarkFeldman, I've tested your code, and I can't make the event NamesChanged triggered. Is there more code to implement (i.e how to implement NamesChangedCommand ?) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I was going  to suggest the xceed checkcombobox

https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckComboBox

But I notice it's not free for commercial use any more. You could build something of your own based on their code though.
https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/CheckComboBox/Implementation/CheckComboBox.cs

The xaml will be in that repo as well.

Comment: Yeah, this one looks (almost) exactly how I need. Not sure how to incorporate it in my project quick enough and not violating the license tough..

Comment: Directly copying the code might be a bit doubtful. It might not do exactly what you want. But it is a known functioning control you could base something on.

Comment: For now Mark's way looks more simple to me. In fact, currently it provides everything what xceed control does excepting toggling of the checkbox by selection. But anyway thank you very much for your help!